# Ruby wamp-client gem - connection to crossbar.io

Tags: ruby, websocket, rubygems, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I'm new in Ruby

I'm trying to use wamp-client gem to establish connection to crossbar.io router. Crossbar have all defaults settings and application created via crossbar template (python as back-end). When I'm connecting via browser everything is fine but when I'm trying to use ruby by simply

```
require  "wamp/client"
wamp_test = WAMP::Client.new("ws://127.0.0.1:8080") 
wamp_test.open
```

I have a `handle_opening_handshake_response': Unhandled opening handshake response # (Net::WS::Error)' error.
I know that to handle handshake my WAMP router should send HTTP 101 switch protocol but it doesn't do that (can't see it in wireshark). 
Please help me out.

Client request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Upgrade: websocket\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n
Sec-Websocket-Key: RggxGCwmcnVuEB08UQMCWA==\r\n
Sec-Websocket-Version: 13\r\n
Sec-Websocket-Protocol: \r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
User-Agent: Ruby\r\n
Host: localhost:8080\r\n
\r\n
Full request URI: http://localhost:8080/
HTTP request 1/1
```

Router return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Crossbar/0.11.1\r\n
Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 07:48:33 GMT\r\n
Cache-Control: max-age=43200, public\r\n
Expires: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 19:48:33 GMT\r\n
Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n
Content-Length: 5085\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 13:07:24 GMT\r\n
\r\n
HTTP response 1/1
Line-based text data: text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the default (generated) Crossbar.io configuration, try: `ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws` instead of `ws://127.0.0.1:8080`. The WAMP-WebSocket transport is on a subpath.

You can check by opening `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ws` in your browser.

Also: your client does not send a valid WebSocket subprotocol list (`Sec-Websocket-Protocol` is empty). Crossbar.io has a config option to make that acceptable (and the assume `wamp.2.json`), but a better behavior would be to activate WebSocket subprotocol negotiation in your WebSocket client library.

Comment: I've added    wamp_test = WAMP::Client.new("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws", :subprotocols => ["wamp.2.json"])  and now Sec-Websocket-Protocol is wamp.2.json but still no connection - same error. This ruby gem is old so I'am not sure if it support WAMPv2

Comment: Looking at the two Ruby implementations of WAMP that a quick Google search could find, based on their age alone neither of them can support WAMP v2.